# Yii2: How to use exceptions?

Tags: php, exception, yii2, crud

I want to create an exception to improve my code a bit but I don't know how to catch it.

I have this simple example (so I can understand it) with the find() function of the Yii2 framework.

```
Persons::find()
    ->select([
        'id',
        'name',
    ])
    ->all();
```

I would like to know how to get an error if the `find()` function can't finish because, for example, the database can't be reach because problems in the database server. So then I can do what [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp) teach.

Comment: having a syntax error in the query or constraint violation can be treated by simply wrapping the callto the query inside `try` and displaying error inside `session->flash` by using catch block, but if the error is related to database connection then you might have to use the `errorAction` of `errorHandler` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a try catch as already answered.

you can refer to this doc to see what sort of options you have in for the exception thrown

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-exception

```
 try{
        $models = Persons::find()
            ->select([
                'id',
                'name',
            ])
            ->all();
    }catch(\yii\db\Exception $e){
        echo $e->getName(); 
    //Get the user-friendly name of this exception
    }
```

You also have options to get the error line no or error code

```
$e->getCode()
$e->getLine()
```

you may also use try catch with finally like below

```
try
    {

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        // to do something in common like close your file handler in this case, or some resource in general
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using try catch as shown below:

I have used DbException as per your case:

```
 try{
        $models = Persons::find()
            ->select([
                'id',
                'name',
            ])
            ->all();
    }catch(\yii\db\Exception $e){
        var_dump($e->getMessage()); //Get the error messages accordingly.
    }
```

https://releasebits.blogspot.com/2018/08/using-exceptions-yii2.html